# Grouping and storing html 'data' attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building an ajax filter for a custom post-type in WordPress. I have a list of anchor tags similar to this:

```
<a href="" class="selected" data-group="1" data-filter="filter-1">Filter 1</a>
<a href="" class="selected" data-group="1" data-filter="filter-2">Filter 2</a>
<a href="" class="selected" data-group="2" data-filter="filter-3">Filter 3</a>
<a href="" class="" data-group="2" data-filter="filter-4">Filter 4</a>
<a href="" class="selected" data-group="2" data-filter="filter-5">Filter 5</a>
<a href="" class="selected" data-group="2" data-filter="filter-6">Filter 6</a>
```

So when the user clicks a tag I apply the class 'selected' to that tag, using the following code:

```
(function($) {
    function build_filter() {
        f = $(".filter a.selected").map(function() {
            return $(this).data('filter');
        })
        .get()
        .join();
        return f;
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.filter a', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        // toggle if selected
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        // get the filter(s)
        filter = build_filter();

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxfilter.ajaxurl,
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                action: 'ajax_filter',
                filter: filter
            },
            success: function (html) {
                $('.product.gallery').empty();
                $('.product.gallery').append(html);
            }
        })
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Then I select all anchor tags that have been 'selected' using the build_filter function. Ultimately I want to create an array that groups all of the 'data-filter's via their respective 'data-group' I know it involves looping the content of

```
$(".filter a.selected").map();
```

But I cant get my head around it, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: can you only have 1 group at a time that has selected on it ?

Answer (score 0):

you are very close just make group of your values on the data-group attribute. I have changed your build_filter function. Please check and if any problem then please let  me know.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 (function($) {
  function build_filter() {
   var obj={};
   f = $(".filter a.selected").each(function() {
   obj[$(this).data('group')]=
         function(datagroup){
         var t=[];
          $(".filter a.selected").each(function() {
           if($(this).data('group')==datagroup)t.push($(this).data('filter'));
          });
          return t;
         }($(this).data('group'));
         
   
   });
   return obj;
  }
  $(document).on('click', '.filter a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // toggle if selected
  //  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  // get the filter(s)
   filter = build_filter();
console.log(filter);
   })
 })(jQuery);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<span class="filter">
<a href="#" class="selected" data-group="1" data-filter="filter-1">Filter 1</a>
<a href="#" class="selected" data-group="1" data-filter="filter-2">Filter 2</a>
<a href="#" class="selected" data-group="2" data-filter="filter-3">Filter 3</a>
<a href="#" class="" data-group="2" data-filter="filter-4">Filter 4</a>
<a href="#" class="selected" data-group="2" data-filter="filter-5">Filter 5</a>
<a href="#" class="selected" data-group="2" data-filter="filter-6">Filter 6</a>
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are welcome, we are here to help each others.  :)